# Partitions and ranking in Bigquery/SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Lets say I have a query pulling all countries, all of their cities, and each cities population.

I want it to only pull the **largest city** for each country. So it is limited to one city (the largest city) per country.

What is the best way to take the "MAX()" city for each country?

I am in BQ writing SQL

Answer (score 0):

Use below simple approach

```
select country, 
  array_agg(struct(city, population) order by population desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from your_table
group by country
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [analytical window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#syntax) and the [qualify clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#filter_window_results):

```
SELECT  country,city,population
  FROM your_table
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY population DESC) = 1
```

Be aware in the unlikely case the two biggest cities of a country having equal population, you'll get two rows in the result set of this query. If you want to avoid this, use the ROW_NUMBER function instead, which in case of a tie chooses just one record. You could also add a tie-breaker to the order by clause of the window function.